# csv file reordering on the basis of correlation matrix

Tags: python, csv, pearson-correlation, reorderlist

I want to reorder the columns of csv file on the basis of correlation matrix( which is computed on csv file). I used IRIS data set and got following correlation matrix

```
       sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
```

sepal_length      1.000000    -0.109369      0.871754     0.817954
sepal_width      -0.109369     1.000000     -0.420516    -0.356544
petal_length      0.871754    -0.420516      1.000000     0.962757
petal_width       0.817954    -0.356544      0.962757     1.000000

Now I want to rearrange the csv columns, so that high correlated columns comes next to each other. Later on I will generate graphs on the basis of new csv.
Here is a code where I try to solve my issue, but this solution is not suitable for large csv file `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv') if ((a['sepal_length']['sepal_width']) < (a['sepal_length']['petal_length']))and(a['sepal_length']['sepal_width']) < (a['sepal_length']['petal_width'])and (a['sepal_length']['petal_width']) < (a['sepal_length']['petal_length']): df1_reorder = df1[['sepal_length', 'petal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_width', 'species']] # rearrange column here df1_reorder.to_csv('sample_reorder3.csv', index=False)`

Comment: looking a solution in python

Comment: Please provide your source code, so we can help you find your error. If you haven't tried yet, please do so. Add any error messages to your question as well.

Comment: Here is a code where I try to solve my issue, but this solution is not suitable for large csv file        data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')          if ((a['sepal_length']['sepal_width']) < (a['sepal_length']['petal_length']))and(a['sepal_length']['sepal_width']) < (a['sepal_length']['petal_width'])and (a['sepal_length']['petal_width']) < (a['sepal_length']['petal_length']):   df1_reorder = df1[['sepal_length', 'petal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_width', 'species']] # rearrange column here
df1_reorder.to_csv('sample_reorder3.csv', index=False)

Comment: Just to add my previous comments, in the if block, the input values to attributes (sepal_length etc) is provided through correlation matrix          sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
sepal_length      1.000000    -0.109369      0.871754     0.817954
sepal_width      -0.109369     1.000000     -0.420516    -0.356544
petal_length      0.871754    -0.420516      1.000000     0.962757
petal_width       0.817954    -0.356544      0.962757     1.000000

Comment: Please move the code to your question. Click the edit button, paste it, select the code, type control-K to format it.  Please take the tour of this site to understand how it works.  Just click on the "?" at the top right of the screen. Thanks.